# how to fix "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" in python pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

hello I want to receive solution in this place

I am a newbie in python programing

I am making something with tools

but I stoped coding since crash occurred due to some problem

let me show you my tools
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NpRi.png)

when i click update, print

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

function process
1. automatic update kuf_name(bring global_nikname)

```
def CHANGE_MYNAME():
        #self.kuf_myname.text = v_myname
        self.global_nikname.textChanged['QString'].connect(self.kuf_myname.setText)
```

2. click the update button

```
#전적 업데이트
    print(type(self.global_nikname.text()))
    if(self.global_nikname.text() != '' ):
        self.kuf_update.clicked.connect(lambda : RANK_UPDATE(self, 'kuf', self.kuf_myrace.currentText(), self.global_nikname.text() , self.kuf_yourname.text(), self.kuf_yourace.currentText(), self.kuf_map.currentText()))
    else:
        self.kuf_update.clicked.connect(lambda : RANK_UPDATE(self, 'kuf', self.kuf_myrace.currentText(), self.kuf_myname.text(), self.kuf_yourname.text(), self.kuf_yourace.currentText(), self.kuf_map.currentText()))
        print("global_nikname is empty")
```

RANK_UPDATE funtion below:

```
        def RANK_UPDATE(self, game, myrace, myname,yourname, yourace, gamemap):
          print(type(self.global_nikname))
          kuf_worksheet_history.append_row(['',today, '1500',myrace, myname, yourname, yourace, gamemap])
```

I gusess this cause, Rank_update receive value(self.kuf_myname.text(), myname) type is QString
it is not type string
but I can't fix code

how to fix that?

Comment: omg!!! it's works!!!...but i have additional question
why dose no exist QString?i mad by qtdesigner

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: the solution exam
origina code :
self.global_nikname.textChanged['QString'].connect(self.kuf_myname.setText)

solution code:
self.global_nikname.textChanged[str].connect(self.kuf_myname.setText)

type change Qsring -> str

Comment: Good. For future reference, always remember to provide a minimal reproducible example of your code, otherwise it may be really hard (if not impossible) for us to understand where the problem is and then help you. Also, take some time to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Since you're a beginner, I also suggest you to carefully study the [style guide for python code (aka PEP8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); I know, it's long, but well written code is easier to read and debug (especially if someone has to read it in order to help you).

Comment: @magnus QString has been deprecated for years, PyQt bets on the compatibility of native python types, so str should be used. It seems that you are using a very old code.